# Xcode 7 : Is LLDB autocompletion with Swift still broken or is it me?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7

Is LLDB autocompletion still broken with Swift or is it me ?

When debugging Obj-c code in the same project the completion works well. When it's in swift nothing shows up :(

Edit : Running XCode 7.1.1 build 7B1005 
Edit : XCode 7.2 (7C68), still broken.

Comment: I think it is still broken, at least for me. I hope they are working on this, and also on Refactoring in Swift, which is also only available in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

HOORAY. XCode 7.3 finally fixed it.